# Read property in @Table class in springboot application

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

I have a class in springboot application

```
@Table("abc")
class ABCDAO{
//getters and setters
}
```

In this class, I want to access property from application.properties file or system environment.

I tried

```
@Value("${test}")
val test: String = ""
```

but unable to read the same.

Comment: `@Table` isn't enough to be added to Spring's context. In order to `@Value` to work, the bean needs to be initialised by spring. You could e.g. add `@Entity` to `ABCDAO` and `@EntityScan` in your `Application`

Comment: Additional to the previous comment a table would not be a dao but an entity.

Comment: {@Value} injects only to classes that are scanned by spring, You can add {@Component} and {@PropertySource} annotations on class. But when class is initialized with new operator those values will remain with their default values. Iam just curious to know what you really want to do

Comment: @RaviTeja based on a propery I want to replace a value in setter method

Comment: @msp there is only EntityScan but no Entity annotation

Comment: I know but how it helps you on using on Entity class, while persisting or retrieving an entity from db that value will not be replaced since they are initialized with new operator. Correct me if iam wrong??